# Unity plugin for Android Studio.

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

Straight to the point, Im trying to run a small program of unity within an android application created on android studio. 
The android application has its own functionality. Eg. after opening the maps API(in android studio), I want to click on a location and then want a small program of unity scene(augmented reality) to start. I want help and I don't have any idea how to do this.

This is the unity application that I want to integrate within my android App. I want to make a unity plugin that can run within an android application instead of creating the entire application in unity.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNwduUQrlJs&t=6s

Comment: That's not something you can do with Unity. You can start a unity app from another but you can't embed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that. What you can do is to create another unity application which will have just the functionalities you want after clicking map location. If you install such app on your Android device, you can then trigger opening this unity app from your Android app by using custom uri schemes. But there is no way to create Unity 'plugin' to launch within android application.